# Algorithm to find array elements that a[i] > 2a[j] with i<j

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, data-structures

Im trying to find an algorithm which returns array elements that a[i] > 2a[j] with i < j in O(nlogn). I can think how to implement this algorithm using double for but i cant implement it in O(nlogn). Does anyone have an idea about how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First, try to come up with an algorithm which counts number of inversions in a given array. There is a classical well-known algorithm for such problem.

Comment: Can i implement that using merge sort algorithm?

Comment: Yes, it is a usual way of solving such problems.